# bitcoin-abe code, what does "dotdot": "../" * (env['PATH_INFO'].count('/') - 1) mean?

Tags: python, bitcoin

i am a beginner and reading the code of ABE, it can be found here https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe.
In abe.py, there is code like this:

```
page = {
        "title": [escape(ABE_APPNAME), " ", ABE_VERSION],
        "body": [],
        "env": env,
        "params": {},
        "dotdot": "../" * (env['PATH_INFO'].count('/') - 1),
        "start_response": start_response,
        "content_type": str(abe.template_vars['CONTENT_TYPE']),
        "template": abe.template,
        "chain": None,
        }
```

What does env mean here?  Many other places in this file also use env, is this a build-in function? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't know ABE, but I'll bet it reads an environment variable, and `PATH_INFO` is the path of the script. So that counts the number of slashes in the script path, subtracts 1, and then repeats `../` that many times.

Comment: Actually, it's probably like PHP's `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` which contains the part of the URL after the script name. So if the script is `/foo/bar/baz`, and the URL is `/foo/bar/baz/p1/p2/p3`, `PATH_INFO` contains `/p1/p2/p3`.

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/web-sig/2007-January/002475.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar, the link helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `*`, when used with a string and an integer, repeats the string.

```
   "a" * 20
=> 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
  "ab" * 20
=> 'abababababababababababababababababababab'
```

The statement

```
"dotdot": "../" * (env['PATH_INFO'].count('/') - 1),
```

assigns `dotdot` to several `../`s. If the environment variable `PATH_INFO` has 10 `/` in it, then `dotdot` is assigned to `"../" * 9`, which is equal to `"../../../../../../../../../"`